# Sessions on WCF host

Tags: c#, wcf, session

I have this WCF client which creates a reliable session and call RegisterClient on it.

```
PreorderServiceClient PreOrders
{
  get
  {
      InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);
      var p = new PreorderServiceClient(context, "netTcpPreorderService");

      p.RegisterClient(Environment.MachineName, "event");

      return p;
    }    
}
```

The binding is configured as an infinite timeout reliable session.

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpPreorderService" openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="infinite" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="true" />
    </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

Now this property was only supposed to be called once or if the channel is faulted, but because of a bug it was called once a second or something like that.

Now after a few hours every time the property was called the exception

> reliable session has been refused by the RM Destination. Server

would be thrown and no other client could connect anymore.

Now I would like to know if I put the inactivityTimeout to 1 second that the exception would still be thrown. Will the session be removed on the host after the inactivity timeout expires?